# Post null no edit MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Olá, tenho a seguinte situação, meu `Edit` retorna um grupo de `Classes` preenchidas para a edição. Na minha `View` os dados são preenchidos corretamente, porém, quando faço a edição de um campo e mando salvar no `Edit (Post)` o meu `Model` chega zerado, ou seja, `NULL`. Eu já descobri que é por causa do `Partial`, têm alguma outra forma de eu realizar?

abaixo segue meu código:

**CONTROLLER (GET)**

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var cadastro = new Cadastro(); // Inicializa o Grupo de Classes...

        cadastro.Pessoa = new Pessoa();
        cadastro.Fisica = new Fisica();
        cadastro.Juridica = new Juridica();

        cadastro.Pessoa = db.Pessoas.Find(id);

        if (cadastro.Pessoa == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        if (cadastro.Pessoa.Tipo == "F")
        {
            cadastro.Fisica = db.Fisicas.Find(id);
        }
        else
        if (cadastro.Pessoa.Tipo == "J")
        {
            cadastro.Juridica = db.Juridicas.Find(id);
        }

        return View(cadastro);
    }
```

**VIEW EDIT**

```
@model CodeFirst.Models.Cadastro

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Fisica.IdPessoa)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Juridica.IdPessoa)

        @if (Model.Pessoa.Tipo == "F") {
            <p>Pessoa Fisica:</p>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="F" checked="checked" class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="J" class="radio">
            <script> $('.boxf').show(); </script>
        } else
        if (Model.Pessoa.Tipo == "J")
        {
           <p>Pessoa Juridica:</p>
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="F" class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="radio" value="J" checked="checked" class="radio">
            <script> $('.boxf').show(); </script>
        }

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pessoa.Documento)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pessoa.Documento)

        <div class="boxf">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/_PessoaFisica.cshtml", Model.Fisica)
        </div>

        <div class="boxj">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/_PessoaJuridica.cshtml", Model.Juridica)
        </div>
        <div class="row marginCimaBaixo text-right">
             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Salvar Cadastro"   />
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>  
}
```

**CONTROLLER (POST), AQUI QUE O CADASTRO CHEGA NULL !**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Cadastro cadastro)
    {
    }
```

**CLASSE CADASTRO**

```
public class Cadastro
{
    public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
    public Fisica Fisica { get; set; }
    public Juridica Juridica { get; set; }
}
```

**SOLUÇÃO**

Solução bem simples, o meu `EditorTemplates` tem que ser o mesmo nome da minha `Class`

ao invés de usar

`@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/_PessoaFisica.cshtml", Model.Fisica)`

usar:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Fisica)
```

Comment: pode postar também sua classe `Cadastro`?

Comment: sim @JedaiasRodrigues vou alterar a pergunta com a classe, obrigado

Comment: Pode fazer a seguinte alteração e fizer se o objecto continua a chegar a null `[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([FromUri]Cadastro cadastro)`

Comment: @JoseRocha vou tentar aqui, so um momento

Comment: @Furlan enganei-me onde esta `[FromUri]` devia de estar `[FromBody]` desculpe. Visto ser um metodo Post a data ira pelo body não pelo Uri

Comment: @JoseRocha esse comando: `[FromBody]` serve para `MVC`? ou é so para `WebAPI`

Comment: @Furlan é apenas para `HttpRequestMessage` normalmente usado para `WebApi`, mas reparei que o metodo é uma `ActionResult`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32737/discussion-between-furlan-and-jose-rocha).

Comment: Poderia usar um Enum, em vez de Tipo = "F" hauhauha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUÇÃO**

Solução bem simples, o meu `EditorTemplates` tem que ser o mesmo nome da minha `Class`

ao invés de usar

`@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/_PessoaFisica.cshtml", Model.Fisica)`

usar:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Fisica)
```